# BK Bandpass filter in R and Gibbs phenomenon

Tags: r, filter

I have a time series z

```
          Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
1922 -0.25108773 -0.27732553 -0.29703807 -0.30274000 -0.30323653 -0.28441682 -0.24106527 -0.18705071 -0.17440826 -0.17291725 -0.19116734 -0.21678948
1923 -0.24487998 -0.26658925 -0.28613991 -0.29674346 -0.29335742 -0.28325761 -0.23326680 -0.18697904 -0.18443807 -0.18144226 -0.18190910 -0.21574376
1924 -0.24465806 -0.27349425 -0.29925888 -0.30386766 -0.30250722 -0.27464960 -0.23390958 -0.19300616 -0.17910621 -0.17869576 -0.19611839 -0.20447324
1925 -0.25326812 -0.27344637 -0.29352971 -0.30947682 -0.30872025 -0.27604449 -0.24065208 -0.19676031 -0.17172229 -0.18484153 -0.19542607 -0.21841577
1926 -0.25214568 -0.27450911 -0.29438956 -0.30392114 -0.30619846 -0.29089168 -0.24829621 -0.20204202 -0.18621514 -0.18808172 -0.19708748 -0.22629595
1927 -0.25107357 -0.27204514 -0.29494695 -0.30751442 -0.30800040 -0.28569694 -0.24655626 -0.19547608 -0.19018517 -0.18866641 -0.20132372 -0.22084811
1928 -0.24733214 -0.27490388 -0.28780308 -0.30407576 -0.30857301 -0.28629658 -0.23872777 -0.19590465 -0.18437917 -0.18274289 -0.19936931 -0.22368973
1929 -0.25531870 -0.27264628 -0.29418746 -0.30385231 -0.31022219 -0.27931003 -0.23404912 -0.19538227 -0.17226595 -0.18465123 -0.19072933 -0.22043396
1930 -0.24735028 -0.27386782 -0.29193707 -0.29925459 -0.30039372 -0.28014958 -0.23551136 -0.19511701 -0.18006660 -0.18282789 -0.20113355 -0.22095253
1931 -0.24903438 -0.27439043 -0.29219506 -0.30312159 -0.30557600 -0.28180333 -0.22676008 -0.19048014 -0.18982644 -0.18459638 -0.19550196 -0.22127202
1932 -0.25870503 -0.27650825 -0.28521052 -0.30685609 -0.30896898 -0.28378619 -0.23614859 -0.18945699 -0.17575919 -0.17820312 -0.19620912 -0.21774873
1933 -0.24187599 -0.25575287 -0.28325644 -0.29554461 -0.29018996 -0.27040369 -0.23514812 -0.19935749 -0.18732198 -0.18606057 -0.19327237 -0.22321366
1934 -0.24793807 -0.26986056 -0.29217378 -0.30479126 -0.30199154 -0.27574924 -0.24097380 -0.18560708 -0.18643606 -0.18501770 -0.19375478 -0.22418002
1935 -0.25587642 -0.27805131 -0.29239104 -0.30784907 -0.30459449 -0.28216514 -0.23839965 -0.20137460 -0.18619998 -0.18328896 -0.20121286 -0.22869388
1936 -0.25322320 -0.28025116 -0.29713940 -0.30800346 -0.31177201 -0.28473251 -0.23552472 -0.20313945 -0.18251793 -0.18383941 -0.20554430 -0.23061875
1937 -0.26268769 -0.28529769 -0.30230641 -0.31107806 -0.30183547 -0.28324508 -0.23840574 -0.19862786 -0.19297314 -0.19392849 -0.19603212 -0.22877177
1938 -0.25445601 -0.28160871 -0.29837676 -0.29879519 -0.30328832 -0.28288226 -0.23577573 -0.19521124 -0.18393512 -0.19039895 -0.20537533 -0.21924241
1939 -0.25180969 -0.28199995 -0.29601764 -0.30147945 -0.30372884 -0.27837795 -0.23720063 -0.19929773 -0.18770674 -0.19341142 -0.20753282 -0.22484697
1940 -0.15145157 -0.16596690 -0.17572643 -0.18225920 -0.18823836 -0.17504012 -0.16019626 -0.12920340 -0.12369614 -0.12024704 -0.12891992 -0.14234080
1941 -0.10045275 -0.11095497 -0.11585389 -0.11932455 -0.11976700 -0.11653216 -0.10259231 -0.08271703 -0.07621320 -0.07184160 -0.07284514 -0.07385666
1942  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1943  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1944  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1945  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1946  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1947  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1948  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1949  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1950  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1951  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1952  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1953  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1954  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1955  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1956  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1957  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1958  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1959  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1960  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
1961  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

[image]

and I want to perform a banpassfilter at 9.7 months and 16 months. I have applied the bkfilter (package mfilter)

[image]

However, after 1942 when z is zero the filter shows still some small cycles. In a previous tread ([Band-pass filter in R: weird behaviour at the end of time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924896/band-pass-filter-in-r-weird-behaviour-at-the-end-of-time-series)) it was suggested to me that this behaviour could be caused by the Gibbs phenomenon. I have then corrected the bkfunction as described here http://www.gla.ac.uk/media/media_219052_en.pdf

```
### Baxter-King filter
modbkfilter <- function(x,pl=NULL,pu=NULL,nfix=NULL,typeBK=c("regular","modified"),type=c("fixed"),drift=FALSE)
{
    if(is.null(drift)) drift <- FALSE
    xname=deparse(substitute(x))
    type = match.arg(type)

    if(is.null(type)) type <- "fixed"

    if(is.ts(x))
        freq=frequency(x)
    else
        freq=1

    if(is.null(pl))
    {
        if(freq > 1)
            pl=trunc(freq*1.5)
        else
            pl=2
    }

    if(is.null(pu))
        pu=trunc(freq*8)

    b = 2*pi/pl
    a = 2*pi/pu

    n = length(x)

    if(n<5)
        warning("# of observations in Baxter-King filter < 5")

    if(pu<=pl)
        stop("pu must be larger than pl")
    if(pl<2)
    {
        warning("in Baxter-King kfilter, pl less than 2 , reset to 2")
        pl = 2
    }

    if(is.null(nfix))
        nfix = freq*3

    if(nfix>=n/2)
        stop("fixed lag length must be < n/2")

    j = 1:(2*n)
    if(typeBK=="regular") B = as.matrix(c((b-a)/pi,(sin(j*b)-sin(j*a))/(j*pi)))
    if(typeBK=="modified") B = as.matrix(c(
                                        (b-a)/pi,
                                        ((sin(j*b)-sin(j*a))/(j*pi)) * (sin((2*pi*j)/(2*nfix+1))/((2*pi*j)/(2*nfix+1)))
                                        ))

    AA = matrix(0,n,n)

    if(type=="fixed")
    {
        bb = matrix(0,2*nfix+1,1)
        bb[(nfix+1):(2*nfix+1)] = B[1:(nfix+1)]
        bb[nfix:1] = B[2:(nfix+1)]
        bb = bb-sum(bb)/(2*nfix+1)

        for(i in (nfix+1):(n-nfix))
            AA[i,(i-nfix):(i+nfix)] = t(bb)
    }

    xo = x
    x = as.matrix(x)
    if(drift)
        x = undrift(x)

    x.cycle = AA%*%as.matrix(x)
    x.cycle[c(1:nfix,(n-nfix+1):n)] = NA
    x.trend = x-x.cycle
    if(is.ts(xo))
    {
        tsp.x = tsp(xo)
        x.cycle=ts(x.cycle,star=tsp.x[1],frequency=tsp.x[3])
        x.trend=ts(x.trend,star=tsp.x[1],frequency=tsp.x[3])
        x=ts(x,star=tsp.x[1],frequency=tsp.x[3])
    }
    res <- list(cycle=x.cycle,trend=x.trend,fmatrix=AA,title="Baxter-King Filter",
                xname=xname,call=as.call(match.call()),
                type=type,pl=pl,pu=pu,nfix=nfix,method="bkfilter",x=x)

    return(structure(res,class="mFilter"))
}
```

However the results does not change much

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

From equation three in the paper:

[image: equation 3]

the divisor is `(2K + 1)`, but you have used `(2*nfix + 1)`, and since `j <= 1:(2*n)`, why doesn't `K <= 2*n` or `(2*2*n + 1)` in your code?  `nfix` does not equal `2*n` from what I see.